# Generation of /proc/net/dev content

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What is the location of the function that actually generates the content of `/proc/net/dev` statistics?. It used to be at `linux/net/core/dev.c`

Comment: Yes you are right. It is net/core/dev.c

Comment: @arkadish Which kernel version?

Comment: My kernel is 3.5.0. There was a function called dev_get_info that called sprintf_stats that actually printed the content , but its changed . I found this here  : http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/linux/2001-May/003621.html

Comment: @arkadish In 3.10.x this is done in net/core/net-proc-fs.c: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/net-procfs.c?v=3.10#L77 In 3.5.x it seems this is moved under some of the other net directories.